# Ansible-Windows Python Installation

Tags: python, windows, ansible

For one of my Windows Server using Ansible I need to download the Python exe in a a Source directory and then do installation and store it to a Target Directory. Both Source/Target are different locations

How can I overide the default software installation path in Windows and set it to a adhoc one as per project requirements?

I'm using the below playbook but it freezes/hangs with no error or any output:

```yaml
---
- name: Install Python
  hosts: win

  tasks:
    - name: Download the latest version of Python from the official website
      win_get_url:
        url: >-
          https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.0/python-3.10.0-amd64.exe
        dest: 'C:\TEMP01\'

    - name: Install Python
      win_package:
        path: 'C:\TEMP01\python-3.10.0-amd64.exe'
        arguments: 'INSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files\Python320'
        state: present
```

Can you tell me how to pass the `arguments` flag?